# update query corrupts characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

my sql update works correctly but it changes the turkish characters. update query changes turkish characters like ı to i etc. here is my query:

```
set @updstatement = 'UPDATE ' + @table_name + ' SET ' + @text_col + '= ''' + @newText + ''' WHERE ' + @id_col + '= ''' + @cur_Id + '''';
                PRINT @updstatement
                exec sp_executesql @updstatement 
                PRINT 'Updated: ' + @cur_Id;
```

I have tried `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` and `COLLATE TURKISH_CI_AS` options but nothing changed. Datatype of column is ntext. Collate setting of table's database is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Collate setting of table is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Collate setting of column is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Before update I can see that turkish characters are stored correctly in the table's column. After update query data of column is corrupted. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Don't inject your values! Parametrise your statements and quote your object names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, don't inject raw values into your dynamic SQL statements. It's a big SQL injection issue and there is no excuse to ever do it.

I suspect you're using a `varchar` and the combination of using a non-parametrised statement is causing the problem. If this doesn't solve the issue, you need to provide an example that replicates the problem (note the guessed data types):

```
DECLARE @table_name sysname,
        @textcol sysname,
        @newtext nvarchar(50), --Guessed datatype
        @id_col sysname,
        @cur_id int; --Guessed dataytpe

DECLARE @updstatement nvarchar(MAX);
SET @updstatement = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + N' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@text_col) + N' = @newtext WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@id_col) + N' = @cur_id;';
PRINT @updstatement; --Your debugging friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@newtext nvarchar(50), @cur_id int', @newtext = @newtext, @cur_id = @cur_id;
```

Comment: Hey @Larnu, Executing parametrized query solved my problem. You are also right about sql injection issue. Characters are not corrupted and it is much safer now. Thank you!